# fpdf html table text break into cell not work

Tags: php, pdf, html-table, fpdf

i'm using fpdf library with html table class that give me the possibility to write table with table tr and td

how is possible to write two value into same cell of html table? i tryed with br and \n but not work.

this is my code

```
$html = "
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<td width='240' height='90'>$detail[name] $detail[vase] $detail[quality]</td>
<td width='70' height='90'>$logistic_date</td>
<td width='70' height='90'>$detail[lot]</td>
<td width='60' height='90'>$warehouse</td>
<td width='220' height='90'>$detail[note]</td>
<td width='50' height='90'>$detail[qxb_def]</td>
<td width='50' height='90'>$detail[quantity_def]</td>
</tr>
</table>"; 

    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
}

$pdf->Output();
```

i need to show

```
<td>
$detail[name]
$detail[vase]
$detail[quality]
</td>
```

Comment: Are you sure this didnt work `<td width='240' height='90'>$detail[name]<br>$detail[vase]<br>$detail[quality]</td>`

Comment: Of course you might have to increase the `height='90'`

Comment: If you mean the "Write HTML tables" script: no, it doesn't support line break in cells.

Comment: try to search `rowspan`